# Declared variable behaving differently to hard coded string

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I am trying to set a like parameter into a variable and allow that variable to accept wild cards (mssql 2005). If I use my parameter set to '%' it only returns a partial subset but if I hard code the query to use '%' it returns the full set. Why might the variable behave differently to the string?

```
DECLARE @wareno char(4); 
SET @wareno = '%';
select @wareno as a, * from waredesc where wareno like @wareno;
```

vs

```
DECLARE @wareno char(4); 
SET @wareno = '%';
select @wareno as a, * from waredesc where wareno like '%';
```

The full scenario is switching based on a flag but is reproducible under the code above

```
DECLARE @wareno char(4); 
DECLARE @delprods bit;

/**
SET THESE PARAMETERS
**/
SET @wareno = '1'; 
SET @delprods = 'true'; /** if true all the warehouses should also be emptied for safety - products are held at a company level!**/

IF @delprods = 1
BEGIN
    SET @wareno = '%';
END
select @wareno as a, * from waredesc where wareno like @wareno;
```

Thanks

Comment: But what are you trying to do? you haven't specify what strings to compare using the `LIKE` predicate, just `like '%'` Why??

Comment: I am actually switching @wareno between a preentered value and a wildcard based on another flag. Under some scenarios I need to override the entered value and to select all wareno

Comment: @user1800273 Are you trying to find all `wareno` that contains the string literal character `%`??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `char(4)` variable will be padded out with three trailing spaces.

These are [significant in a `LIKE` pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) and it will only match values ending in three spaces. Use `varchar(4)` instead.

Comment: Martin : I thought Sql Server uses different `execution` if the value is present at the `compile` time or if it is `unknown` .If the value is known then sql server generates the optimal plan based on the static value else it estimates the `number of rows`.Am i right ?

Comment: @praveen - That is (kind of) true but doesn't affect the OP's question. If the value is a parameter it will be sniffed and compiled as per the first value passed. If it is a variable SQL Server will just use general estimates. For either `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` can be used to get it to take account of the actual runtime value.